# How to programmatically read the plan text password when user register?

Tags: users, user-registration

I have code to check the strength of password. It returns the strength of password.

What I want is, I want to read the plan text password when user registering. Then I need to pass that password to my code and store the strength of password to user meta.

The problem I face was, I could not finder any action / filter to read the password when user is registering the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an action https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/check_passwords/ which can be used to add your checking code.

You could save your 'strength indicator' by adding it to $_POST and then re-accessing it when the user data is saved.   Actions for that are https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register and https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/profile_update.

These actions are listed on https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference.  Alternatively when looking for an action or filter to suit your coding needs, one can always look in the code.   Either scroll through or do search in files for 'do_action' and 'apply_filters' and you'll see what's available and when it's called.

Interestingly WP has a 'pw_weak' checkbox that on a global search does not appear to get processed anywhere, but if they've ticked it, it should be in the $_POST variable.  ON user_register or profile_update, you could possibly check that and use that as your weak/strong indicator?

This works:

```
function store_weak ($user_id) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['pw_weak'] ) )
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'password_strength', 'weak');
        else 
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'password_strength', 'strong');
}
add_action ('profile_update', 'store_weak', 10 ,1 );
add_action ('user_register', 'store_weak', 10 ,1 );
```

This also works:

```
function check_strength () {
    $_POST['strength_level'] = 'medium'; // or whatever
}

function store_weak ($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['strength_level'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'strength_level', sanitize_text_field($_POST['strength_level']));
        }
}
add_action ('check_passwords', 'check_strength', 10 ,1 );'
```

Comment: Thanks . `add_action ('check_passwords', 'check_strength', 10 ,1 );'` Do you know that when will trigger this action? All registration, login, etc... I could not find when this trigger.

Comment: This page (linked above) describes when each action runs. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Administrative_Actions, OR use a text editor like notepad++ on your local wordpress test install, you can search for the text of the action and find exactly where they are called and how, OR from the developer resources https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/, if you click on 'view trac' you will be taken directly to where the hook is called. EG: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1773.